# Java 8 count objects with multiple values

Tags: java, lambda, count, java-stream

Assume I have a class called Combination that consists of two fields whoose type is a simple enum value.

Examples:

`new Combination(Animal.DOG, Animal.CAT)`,

`new Combination(Animal.CAT, Animal.APE)`,

`new Combination(Animal.MOUSE, Animal.DOG)`

I have a collection of combinations and I'd like to count the total occurences of each animal so that the example output would look like:

```
DOG=2
CAT=2
MOUSE=1
APE=1
```

I already tried different approches, but I didn't found a solution yet. Is there any simple way to do this in java 8?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can start with for loop to get the idea of an algorithm

Comment: What are the accessors for `Combination`?

Comment: What are the different approaches that you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
Map<Animal, Long> counts = combinations.stream()
        .flatMap(c -> Stream.of(c.getFirst(), c.getSecond()))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Alternatively:

```
Map<Animal, Long> counts = Stream.concat(
            combinations.stream().map(Combination::getFirst),
            combinations.stream().map(Combination::getSecond))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```